# Button not displaying properly when converting from ui to py file PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I am fairly new to pyqt5, so still learning. I am creating a Home page for a small desktop app I am creating. I am using Qt designer to help me with the code.
My home-page looks like this in Qt designer:
[image: o]

Here, the Launch Tool button is being properly displayed, but when I convert this to py file and run it in spyder, this is how it becomes:
[image]
This is the full code for the HomePage generated by Qt designer:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_HomeWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, HomeWindow):
        HomeWindow.setObjectName("HomeWindow")
        HomeWindow.resize(492, 380)
        HomeWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(HomeWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 0);\n"
"")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame_3)
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_4)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 30))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 220, 20);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        HomeWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(HomeWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(HomeWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, HomeWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        HomeWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("HomeWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("HomeWindow", "Arrhenius Solver"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("HomeWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">Instructions</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; text-decoration: underline;\">For calculations without Humidity:</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">1. Please leave all the Humidity fields empty</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">2. Atleast 2 values each of Temperature, Degradation, and Time are required to calculate the parameters.</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">3. More than 2 (upto 7) inputs can be provided to increase accuracy.</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; text-decoration: underline;\">For calculations with Humidity:</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">1. Please fill the Humidity text fields as well</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">2. Atleast 3 values each of Temperature, Degradation, Time and Humidity are required to calculate the parameters</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">3. More than 3 (upto 7) inputs can be provided to increase accuracy<br /></span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("HomeWindow", "Launch Tool"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    HomeWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_HomeWindow()
    ui.setupUi(HomeWindow)
    HomeWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please help me fix this, I want it like it's being displayed in Qt designer

Comment: It shows fine to me in python IDLE. Can you try it in different IDE?

Comment: The above link solved my question, thank you so much!